# How to change the mouse cursor to ' No' when a text box is read only?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have a number of `TextBox`es on many `Page`s. Some of the `TextBox`es are in the read only mode. 
When a text box is read only, I need the mouse cursor to be a 'No'-cursor. It is possible to set in XAML, something like `Cursor="No"`, but I want to make it in a general way. I don't want to change every page and text box. Is there any way?

Comment: You should read more about the WPF concepts: styling, triggers, and dependency properties. Then you will see that you can very easily solve your issue. It's a basic WPF topic.

Comment: Yes ... Sure i do. Thanks

Comment: Xaml Styles should be the answer: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23304125/how-to-create-a-read-only-textbox-style](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23304125/how-to-create-a-read-only-textbox-style)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the style to the Application resources. It will be applied to all TextBoxes:

```
<Style TargetType="TextBox">
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="IsReadOnly" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="Cursor" Value="No"/>
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

Comment: Thanks Dude Works fine :-)